# React Load Data From DB & Store in State Only Once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So here's my situation. I have a component that loads some data from the database, like so:

```
const task= fetch(`http://example.com`)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                items: result
            })
        });

        addTask(task);
```

Now, if I add this code to the `componentWillMount` method, it does work however, every time I load the component, this method will fire and I don't want it calling the database every time. I want it called once on first load and then stored in the state and never called again.

And because I am rendering a list of items, I have to manually set this `items` variable in the constructor to avoid `null` errors:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        items: [],
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I load this data only once and then set it to the `items` state variable. I have tried adding all this code to the reducer of the component (I am using `redux`), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving what you are trying to do, but every each of them brings up more questions to answer I think.

First question is, lets say you stored your data locally after your first fetch, whats gonna happen if the data on the server changes? You can somehow notify the client side that data is change and then fetch the data again to sync local data. Or maybe you can periodically check for the new data. There are lots of ways to go.

This situation is exists if you load the data on a parent component and pass the data to the component that is gonna use it or use persistent redux or similar solution.

You can go with a 3 library solution like Realm, Firebase or similar. These systems have persistent or local storage options that will reduce the download when you make call to data. But these solutions bring up the need for changing your back-end logic.

Like I said before there is no single way to handle these situations and it really depends on your project and preference.